# Clarifying the consecutive day badges; make it easier to tell if the day counts

Tags: feature-request, badges, consecutive-days, calendar

Ok, so we seem to get new "consecutive day" issue questions once a week and it's always the same answer, so maybe we could find a way to relieve this issue so users could look and see what the system says actually happened.

**Step 1:** Clarify the badges.

Both badges say `Visited the site each day for n consecutive days`. The word "visited" can be misinterpreted easily. A normal person would think "visited" means you, well, *visited* the site (opened the page, it loaded, that's a visit). If certain pages don't count and they want to encourage *use* of the site to count towards the badge, we should really clarify that in the description. How about `Used the site each day for n consecutive days`?

**Step 2:** Show users visited vs used.

Let's prevent the questions constantly popping up. Why not just tell the user directly that the system doesn't consider that they've used the site that day? We already get this nice calendar. So if I miss a day, it's just white. Looks like I didn't even visit that day, who knows what happened.

[image: Before the changes]

<sup>***Note:*** I'm not claiming I visited that day. I didn't. I derped and totally missed that day.</sup>

So, let's say I *had* visited that day, but the system doesn't think I actually "used" the site. In a normal user's eyes, it looks like I just got reset for no apparent reason. "hey, I visited!" Can we not make that box a different color to say, "yeah, you visited, but you didn't *use* the site"?

[image: After the changes]

<sup>*Orange you glad I didn't say banana?*</sup>

Now I have a nice orange box that says I visited the site but didn't use it. There could be other alternatives. The only other thing I thought of was allowing a user to access the logs for how they accessed the site each day, but I thought that was a bit out there and very unlikely to happen.

Comment: In a normal user's eyes, it doesn't matter, because only you can see your days visited calendar. Regular users can't see each other's calendars, and you know if you visited or not, so I don't see this as being a very useful feature.

Comment: @nhinkle: this was (I believe) spawned by http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129311/consecutive-days-bug (see the sad list of related questions). "... you know if you visited or not..." is the problem - the definition of that isn't really clear. The rephrasing seems like a good idea to me, the calendar display would be a nice extra.

Comment: @animuson - you explained the issue in a brilliant way. This is sadly what made me so frustrated in the first place and had me asking these questions. Thank you for clarifying. I hope Jeff Atwood and his team will take your advice seriously.

Comment: (@OferZelig: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/02/farewell-stack-exchange.html - Jeff Atwood is no longer on the team.)